# Wordpress posts in columns

Tags: php, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a wordpress theme. i would like to have three columns with post excerpts. But the problem is that they don't always have the same height (and i don't want them to), so when in one row a post is too high, the next row will start too far away.

Hmmm, i can really explain it, so i created this fiddle to show what i mean:

```
//in the fiddle there is html and css making a clear example of what i mean
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59qyD/1/

As you can see post id#5 is too long, so post #7 doesn't go any more under post #4.

What i would like is to find a solution where the post always "go up" to the previous post in that column. If possible, without any plugins...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a dynamic column height no matter if it's images/posts/products, you can apply [Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

This JS offers you the possibility to fit each new div under the previous div from the above line, and has a great effect of showing it.

Comment: yes, Masonry is very nice. i would like to use a plugin just as last resort, but maybe i'll come to that anyway!  ;)

Comment: You don't need to use a plugin (i'm not sure even if there's one) you just use the JS and make it work for your needs (config the selectors ... etc) ;)

Comment: (+1) I've just checked a demo site and it seems responsive (as additionally requested the author)! Still there are different solutions possible (CSS only - for modern browsers only), PHP+CSS (for all browsers, but should gegerate multiple classes per post) and probably there are more JS solutions (this one is just one of the JS options available)...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP + CSS based solution:

**PHP:**

```
$count = 0;
$count_total = 10; // or use dynamic count: count($all_posts)
$columns = 3;
foreach ( $all_posts as $k=>$v ) {
    $count++;
    $is_first_column = false; // always set to false, then set to true only when the condition matches!
    // Now check is this a post for the first column
    if( $count==1 || ($count-1)%$columns==0 ) { // check if it's 1st and every 4,7,10 post and place it in 'column 1'
        // set additional class for every post that need to be placed in the first column
        $is_first_column = true;
    }

    // Now you can add the additional class to the html markup:
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post col<?php if( !empty( $is_first_column ) ) { echo ' column_1'; } ?>">


}
```

And then use CSS to clear the float for every .column_1.

**CSS:**

```
.column_1 {
    clear: both;
}
```

I used similar approach in multiple projects and it worked. The code above may need to me modified a bit to work for your specific theme, but I hope you'll get the main idea.

It will work immediately after page + CSS load (no waiting for JS to load)! :-)

Comment: is there a way to make this responsive? Let's say, when width < 800px then use only two columns? That would be WOWOW  !!  =)
I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check the following idea (example 1 & 2): (found by searching for: css nth of type odd even) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp (and also note that: The :nth-of-type() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.). So if you need IE8 and earlier, a JS solution would be needed.

Comment: I just realized that you could use the above PHP solution and generate 2 classes for each column! For example, when you have 3 columns use classes: col3_1, co3_2 and col3_3; when you have 2 columns use: col2_1 and col2_2. Then you can style "col3_1, co3_2 and col3_3" for example 960+ width and "col2_1 and col2_2" for less... :-)

Comment: (+1) too :), yes sure there are a lot of native php+css solutions but still, it's limited, and no fade effect on displaying and it could not work on all the browser, as for loading that depends where you push the js in the code :)